AirCompressor copper line to 1 of the smaller tanks was broken I removed to repair and a gallon or so of oval/round beads fell out not metal or glass
Air compressor contained about a gallon or so of beads, not metal or glass, that fell out when removing broken copper line. What are they and why are they there?

I'm not sure of the composition of the beads, however I believe they are there to pull moisture from the air.

Small(1/8 inch diameter) white beads?  Probably the same as those small packets found with new tools.

Probably the wrong site to ask. If they were in the pipe, then I would suspect that they should be removed.

They are Desiccant Air Drying beads.
To be safe, check with the manufacturer. It isn't clear where they were supposed to be, inside a filter or just in the tank.
Since this is Home Improvement SE, I am assuming that this isn't an industrial setup with a separate air dryer. Like a 200HP unit.
But since you have copper lines, you've got something more than the typically hobbyist/light professional pancake compressor with an hose, like a 6 gallon dewalt.
